# group by expression not working properly?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

My code works fine for the below query:

```
CREATE TABLE employee ( employee_id INTEGER, manager_id INTEGER, first_name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, title VARCHAR2(20), salary NUMBER(6, 0) );

 CREATE TABLE manager( manager_id INTEGER NOT NULL, manager_dept VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL ) Here are my tables

SELECT 
DISTINCT E.EMPLOYEE_ID, M.MANAGER_ID, E.FIRST_NAME, 
E.LAST_NAME, CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF, CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE, level
FROM EMPLOYEE E
LEFT OUTER JOIN MANAGER M
ON E.MANAGER_ID=M.MANAGER_ID
WHERE m.manager_id=10
start with e.employee_id >0
connect by NOCYCLE m.manager_id=prior e.employee_id
GROUP BY 
E.EMPLOYEE_ID, M.MANAGER_ID, E.FIRST_NAME, 
E.LAST_NAME, CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF, CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE,LEVEL
```

but i want my result set to grouped by only on employee_id and not all fields

When i use this query below then an error generates "NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION"

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT E.EMPLOYEE_ID, M.MANAGER_ID, E.FIRST_NAME, 
E.LAST_NAME, CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF, CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE, level
FROM EMPLOYEE E
LEFT OUTER JOIN MANAGER M
ON E.MANAGER_ID=M.MANAGER_ID
WHERE m.manager_id=10
start with e.employee_id >0
connect by NOCYCLE m.manager_id=prior e.employee_id
GROUP BY 
E.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Whats wrong with this query??

Comment: You cannot select the columns which are not present in group by until us use any aggregate function.

Comment: so what do i do then?

Comment: if you want to just group by employee_id. Just remover all columns other then employee_id. If you explain the requirement i can help you more

Comment: CREATE TABLE employee (
      employee_id INTEGER,
      manager_id INTEGER,
      first_name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
      last_name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
      title VARCHAR2(20),
      salary NUMBER(6, 0)
  );

CREATE TABLE manager(
manager_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
manager_dept VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
last_name  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
)
 Here are my tables

Answer (score 1):

I assume your employee ID is unique, so by grouping by it, you're grouping by everything else in the query as well. But Oracle doesn't know that. If you were grouping by employee ID only, and you had two employees having the same id, one with last name "Smith" and one with last name "Miller", which one would you like to see? It's either Smith or Miller, as you have only one row of data, so the database doesn't know what to do.

That's why you always have to group by every column that's not aggregated (using SUM, MAX, MIN, or one of the other functions).

You could omit the columns from your result set and the group by, then put the whole query into a subquery, with the outer query selecting the remaining columns from a join of the subquery and the employee table. But trust me, you don't really want to do that, as that version would be much uglier to read and understand than your current query.

Comment: That may be, but it doesn't change my answer. Every column in the result set must either have an aggregate function, or must be included in the group by list.